# Impossible to use html2canvas with ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, html2canvas

I would like to use html2canvas with ie8. I have searched and found flashcanvas to use html2canvas. But, I have a problem in the file html2canvas.js. Everytime the function loadPseudoElement is called :

```
function loadPseudoElement(element, type) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, type),
    content = style.content;
    if (content.substr(0, 3) === 'url') {
        methods.loadImage(_html2canvas.Util.parseBackgroundImage(content)[0].args[0]);
    }
    loadBackgroundImages(style.backgroundImage, element);
}
```

an error appears in the line "var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, type),".

Apparently, getComputedStyle is not handle by ie8. I have tried this :

```
var style = null;
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element, type);
}
else {
    style = element.currentStyle;
}
var content = style.content;
```

but it's still not working.

My JS code to call html2canvas and flashcanvas is :

```
function test(){

    html2canvas($('#contentBody'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            if (typeof FlashCanvas != "undefined") {
                FlashCanvas.initElement(canvas);
            }
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var newImg = window.open(img);
        }     
    });
    return false;
}
```

Could you help me, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html2canvas relies on so many things that IE8 or below doesn't support that you are gonna find it next to impossible to get it working on IE8.